# GCP API doesn't return me the entire projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP API doesn't return me the entire projects in my organization, but only the current project, when I try to do cloudResourceManager.projects.list.
It worked very well before but now suddenly it doesn't work anymore.
Does someone know if anything had been changed?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did your org make IAM changes to the service accounts roles?  Are the projects visible to the user in the webui?

Comment: I didn't make any changes on the org. and yes it is visible on the web

Comment: I just tried the [Example code in Python](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/list), it works fine to me. Could you also try that sample code, and see if you can get all the projects?